# Cannot put HTML element on top of flash

Tags: flash, z-index

No matter what values of z-index I try, I cannot overlay my html div (or img) element on top of this flash animation (see top left corner):

http://www.resident.co.il/aspx/places.aspx?t=4&a=1

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209085/showing-content-over-a-flash-9-swf). The trick is to add the param `wmode`:

```
<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
```

Only add transparency if *you absolutely need it*, as it is more processor-intensive:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
```

Also [see this demonstration](http://www.communitymx.com/content/source/E5141/wmodeopaque.htm).

Comment: Don't forget to also modify the <object> tag too to include: wmode="opaque"

Comment: Hey Paul, your link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Add this param:

```
<param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
```

And if you're using an embed tag add the attribute `wmode="transparent"`