# flowplayer not positioning properly

Tags: html, css, video, slideshow, flowplayer

I've got this structure:

```
<div slideshow>
    <div id=prev>
    <div id=next>
    <div>
        <img>
        <img>
        <a href="link_to_video">
    </div>
</div>
```

It creates a slideshow with two img, a flowplayer video and two arrows.

Everything works fine, but the video appears when the prev arrow finishes. I mean:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/819/sinttuloipc.png/

The left side of the video should begin where the left arrow begins, instead of when the arrow finishes. The arrow is float:left, I've tried with z-index bigger to the arrow and lower to the video, putting the arrow after the video, and so on, but I can't manage to get the video to appear at the left of the main div.

Any idea on how to structure/style the elemens?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
#slideshow {position:relative;}
#prev {position:absolute; left:0; top:40%;}
#next {position:absolute; right:0; top:40%;}
```

Can you try that?

Comment: I tried with position absolute, but it shows it in the same way as now: the video above the arrows, so it is impossible to change to another element in the slide.

Comment: Is it an flash movie? THen see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910738/cannot-put-html-element-on-top-of-flash you should just add the param to ur flash movie, and the button should be on top :)

Comment: it is a flash movie, but I don't create it. It is created in execution-time because of the flowplayer plugin, so I can't add the param.

Comment: You can add param's in flowplayer, see http://static.flowplayer.org/forum/3/73053

Comment: I tried with transparent property as well but it didn't work. Finally, I rejected that idea and I put two images with position:fixed and it seems the problem had benn solved :)